# Why is my function not taking the derivative and substituting?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that takes a function and uses the Taylor Series to make a Taylor Polynomial. However, when I try to take the derivative of the function and subsitute my center('c'), it is giving me an error and I don't know what to fix.

I have tried renaming the function and tired too manually input a function but it will always give me this error. And if I try to put in f(x) it says x has already been called before the function.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import math as mt


###############################################


def factorial(m):
    if m <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return m*factorial(m-1)

x, h = symbols('x, h')
f = Function('f')

def fp(function, m = 10, c = 0, x0 = 1):

    if m < 0 or type(m) != int:
        raise ValueError('Value m must be a positive integer', m)

##Check if m is a positive integer

    if type(c) not in (int, float):

        raise ValueError('Value c must be one a Real Number', c)

##Check if c is valid

################################################

    while i <= m:
        p = p +((f.diff(x, i).subs(x,c)/(factorial(i)))*(x-x0)**i
        i += 1
        return p


## Defin Taylor
################################################



## Plots function
```

I found a Taylor Code online and used it and it works fine by itself but does not like to run in this one.

Comment: Please show the complete and exact error message including traceback.

Comment: fyi you are missing a parenthesis use `p = p +((f.diff(x, i).subs(x,c)/(factorial(i)))*(x-x0)**i)`

Comment: aside from error message,  the `while` loop `return p` after only one iteration, so it seems to be useless

Answer (score 1):

I like it,
it's fixed now.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import math as mt


def factorial(m):
    if m <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return m*factorial(m-1)

x, h = symbols('x, h')
f = Function('f')
print(diff(cos(x),x).subs(x,0)+diff(cos(x),x))

def fp(function, m = 10, c = 0, x0 = 1):

    if m < 0 or type(m) != int:
        raise ValueError('Value m must be a positive integer', m)


    if type(c) not in (int, float):

        raise ValueError('Value c must be one a Real Number', c)


    i = 0 
    p=0
    while i <= m:
        p = p +(((function.diff(x, i).subs(x,c))/(factorial(i)))*(x-c)**i)
        print(p)
        i += 1
    return p
```

test:

[image]